# STM32F4 - how detect removed battery

Tags: stm32f4

I would like use battery backup SRAM in STM32F4 MCU. Is there some way how detect disconnected/removed battery after connecting VDD voltage (after reset)?

Yes, I can save CRC of backup SRAM in RTC backup registers, but I would like get information from some MCU register.

Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vbat is connected internally to the channel 18 of the ADC. You just need to enable the bit VBATE in the CCR ADC register and convert. This channel has internal divider and the read value is 1/4 of the actual one.